# Issue with reading bus signal. Compare to my Modelsim DE 10.2c and 10.4. EDAplayground Modelsim 10.1d has different result

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim, edaplayground

Hi any SystemVerilog experts with Mentor Graphic Modelsim Tool.

I am writing a monitor task to process a simple PCI single word write/read bus event.    Somehow EDAplayground Altera Modelsim 10.1d requires extra clock cycle for unknown reason while my Modelsim DE 10.2c / 10.4 does not.   I want to understand if this is correct.

Here is an example on write monitor class code :

```
     @(negedge bus.MONCLK.FRAMEn);
     @(bus.MONCLK);    // EDA playground Modelsim 10.1d requires this extra clock cycle for getting data right.   It is also required for read as well. 
     address = bus.MONCLK.AD;
     if (bus.MONCLK.CBEn == IO_Write_CMD) begin
        //tran_type = PCI_WRITE;
        write = 1;      // true
        @(bus.MONCLK);
        data = bus.MONCLK.AD;
        status = 1'b1; // success
     end else begin              
        status = 1'b0; // not success
     end
```

Here is an example on read monitor class code :

```
    @(negedge bus.MONCLK.FRAMEn);
     @(bus.MONCLK);     // EDA playground Modelsim 10.1d requires this extra clock cycle for getting data right.   It is also required for read as well. 
     address = bus.MONCLK.AD;
     if (bus.MONCLK.CBEn == IO_Read_CMD) begin
        write = 0;      // false
        @(bus.MONCLK);
        @(bus.MONCLK);
        data = bus.MONCLK.AD;
        status = 1'b1; // success
     end else begin              
        status = 1'b0; // not success
     end
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/7kG   An example shows the correct result if I have this extra clock cycle.   I will get data = c correctly for read or write.
http://www.edaplayground.com/x/TSE  An example shows the wrong result if I removes this extra clock cycle.  I get data = 516 (address) for write and data = z for read.   But, my Modelsim 10.2c and 10.4 will show the correct result (data = c).

Could you help me understand this issue?  Thank you.

Michael

Comment: You might have a race condition on the `data` signal. The signal operations might get scheduled slightly differently on the two simulators Without the showing us the code that is driving that signal it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: It is definitely a scheduling differences. Putting `$display` statements after each `@` show `@(negedge bus.MONCLK.FRAMEn);` and `@(bus.MONCLK);` happen in the same time-stamp in ModelSim 10.1d. I haven't determent if it is a bug in 10.1d or an inherent race condition from the LRM. @Tudor, the full code is available on the the edaplayground links.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I believed that Atlera Modelsim is based the core engine of Modelsim DE.    I would not think that there is a difference.   I did this example with UVM library.  I have the same problem with uvm_info and the wrong data stored in the transaction class packet (not just $display issue).  Could not be scheduling be that much different?  It is able to break my UVM testbench.  I can provide link to UVM testbench if interested.

Comment: Sorry, UVM is complex and can confuse the issue.  SV example here is simple.  Maybe I can put comparison of data to show the mismatch problem.   That may be simple way to see if it is related to $display.  In UVM, I have a mismatch issue that the data is wrong.  So, I know that there is an issue.

Comment: I added comparison (==) to check actual address/data in both examples.   Thank you for any additional comments.

Comment: I appreciate Greg and Tudor.   I like to check LRM too for any insight on signal race and internal delta event scheduling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find an explication for the race condition, but I have found two workarounds that will work with all versions.

One approach is to use a while-loop with the clock as the blocking event and the net as the compare condition.

- `while(bus.MONCLK.FRAMEn!=1'b0) @(bus.MONCLK);`

The other approach is to use tiny delay before or after the `@`. `#1` should be safe so long as your clock is period is greater than a 1 time unit. I do not recommend using both leading and trailing delay, pick one.

- `@(negedge bus.MONCLK.FRAMEn) #1;`
- `#1 @(bus.MONCLK);`

Comment: Greg.  Thank you so much for the example code.  The first example will sample the state of FRAMEn and use only @(bus.MONCLK) to advance.   The second example is to put #1 unit delay to avoid two statement to occurs at the same time.   I think I understand your ideas here.  I will try them out.

Comment: FYI: on this site, thank yous are given via up votes and accepting the best answers (check mark next to an answer). This also helps other users with similar issues find solutions.